# how to read spring beans definitions

Tags: java, spring

I need to read the bean definitions from a Spring context file, practically reading what is inside the XML. I do not want to instantiate beans, I just want to read the content of the file.

While I can write a parser to do so, I imagine Spring already does this. What classes does it use (I am running around the XmlBeanDefinitionReader related classes but I am not sure how to use them)?

How can I load the XML into bean definitions using Spring's classes?

I am using Spring 2.0.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you create an [XmlBeanFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/XmlBeanFactory.html) you can then use the methods in the [ListableBeanFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html) interface to inspect available beans, and get a [BeanDefintion](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html) object as necessary using [getBeanDefinition(beanName)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.html#getBeanDefinition%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Since this is a BeanFactory implementation, with getBean(...) methods, won't it trigger an instantiation of the beans?

Comment: Not until you call `getBean` or `insantiateBean` or `preInsantiateSingletons` etc.